# sub query error when inserting data in postgres

Tags: subquery

" more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" i got this error when executing my query, when i checked my code, there's no sub query.. here is my code:

```
sql = <string>
 insert into tbl_coll_accounts( bill_id ,ctaxdec,nassessedvalue,ncomputed_basic,ncomputed_sef,ncomputed_penalty,ncomputed_discount,nsubtotal,quarter,ctaxyear) values( <%= RPU_billing_id %> ,'<%= RPU_taxdecs %>','<%= RPU_assessvalue %>','<%= basic1 %>','<%= sef1 %>','<%= penalty %>','<%= discount %>','<%= subtotal %>','<%= quartz(i) %>','<%= RPU_lyear %>')
 </string>
acscmd2 = New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand(sql, con)
acscmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

thanks for your help

Comment: "ERROR: 21000"  this was the error code